# angular universal server render wont wait for ajax calls

Tags: angular, angular-universal

iam building my angular unversal eCommerce app using `npm run build:ssr`

when navigate directly to the product URL

the only content i see on the page source is the static content

universal wont wait for ajax (using angular Http )calls to returns

is this a normal behavior ?

if so why universal is need for ?

my component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css'],
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit, IReadServerData, AfterViewInit {


  constructor(private http_service: HttpService, private route: ActivatedRoute
    , public modal_service: ModalWindowState
    , public helper_service: HelperService
    , public server_response_service: ServerResponseService, public loged_user: LogedUserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.Read();
  }


  Read() {

    this.http_service.Get("Product/1")
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.HandleResponse(data)
        }
      );

  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console server side? That's usually the reason

Comment: Are the url fully qualified?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try To use **Promise**. Don't forget to **import toPromise** from **rxjs** at top.

```
this.http_service.Get("Product/1")
 .toPromise()      
 .then(
    data => {
      this.HandleResponse(data)
    }
   );
}
```

Please read comments to resolve issue

Comment: the code still works but same stuff -> ajax content wont show on page source –

Comment: why is this marked as a correct answer? I'm using angular universal with observables and this doesn't work at all